# How to correct linear tick marks that appear in a ListLogLogPlot Frame?

Tags: plotting

When setting the `Frame->True` option in a `ListLogLogPlot`, the FrameTicks on the right and top side are linearly spaced.

Here is an example with the GridLines turned on to highlight the problem:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{{1, 1}, {100, 100}}, Frame -> True, GridLines->All]
```

[image]

Setting `FrameTicks->All` gets the the top and right ticks to show up correctly in log form, but this also adds text labels that I do not want.

```
ListLogLogPlot[{{1, 1}, {100, 100}}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, GridLines->All]
```

[image]

How can I get log tick marks to appear on the right and top without the associated text labels?

Comment: Doing the same evaluation in Mathematica 11 is one way to accomplish it. For the record, you could also control GridLines a little better using something like the following: `ListLogLogPlot[{{1, 1}, {150, 150}}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {{1, 10, 100}, {1, 10, 100}}]`

Comment: Thanks @user6014! I will try this when I install v11, but for now, I will still let to get it working in v10 for my older codes.   Thanks also for the GridLines setting suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated**

```
ListLogLogPlot[{{1, 1}, {100, 100}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, GridLines -> All, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]}, 
                     {Automatic, Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]}}]
```

[image]

---

```
ListLogLogPlot[{{1, 1}, {100, 100}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 GridLines -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, if my question was unclear, but I still want the FrameTicks to appear on the top and right. I just want them to correctly show at log locations.

Comment: @Rashid Updated ... Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, the top version is perfect! Setting the FrameTickStyle font directives is exactly what I needed.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rashid Happy to help.